# libgdx - moving a body in a circular path

Tags: vector, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to achieve a circular movement around another body. Since now I have a `DistanceJoint` between the two bodies but my problem is how to find the right direction where to apply my force.

I tryied this function which is obviously not working:

```java
public void updateCircular(float speed, Vector2 center){
    Vector2 radius = center.sub(this.body.getPosition());
    Vector2 force = radius.rotate90(1).nor().scl(speed);
    this.body.setLinearVelocity(force.x, force.y);
}
```

`center` is the anchor point of my static body and the function is called by the class of my moving body, actually the idea was to call this method in the render part so every time I'd have rotated the vector of the distance between the two bodies of 90 degree to find the tangent vector.

It seems to be a bad idea, so how can I find the tangent vector in every frame in order to move my first object around the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector2 center is being modified every frame, you need to make a copy.

```
public void updateCircular(float speed, Vector2 center){
    Vector2 radius = center.cpy().sub(this.body.getPosition());
    Vector2 force = radius.rotate90(1).nor().scl(speed);
    this.body.setLinearVelocity(force.x, force.y);
}
```

Comment: But if I want a force that is always tangent to the vector of the distance, should I not leave it update every frame?

Comment: A 90 degree angle should be fine,  I tested this out and the bodies move in a circle. I did not add a distanceJoint though.

Comment: It should update every frame, since the distance vector changes. This vector represents a radius of the circle path. A 90 degree angle of this vector is tangential to the circle at the end point.

Comment: I agree, so why do I a need a copy?

Comment: Center.sub subtracts the value from center forever,  so you want to subtract the position from a copy of center

Comment: But "this.body.getPosition()" changes every frame and the Vector2 radius is a new one every time. Anyway it doesn't work with me, where am I wrong?

Comment: It worked, there was a mistake about the input. Many thanks!